# xml button styling is not working in Android Application

Tags: android, xml

I am new in Android Programming. I have  a Sign in button in the application.

```
<Button
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignInStyle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
```

and my ButtonSignInStyle.xml file is as follows

```
<selector xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
          <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#B3E5FC" android:startColor="#B3E5FC"/> 
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp" />
          <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#E1F5FE" android:startColor="#B3E5FC"/>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

But button dissapears when i run the program. In fact, it does not dissapear, I can see very light gray "Sign In" text in the middle.

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot:[Sign In button is above The Sign Up Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzlY8.png)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Maybe change the background color to give more contrast

Answer (score 1):

You can break the problem and make it simpler.

Create **button_background.xml** in drawable folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_state" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_state" />
</selector>
```

Create **xml pressed_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#36b136"
        android:startColor="#1dbf46" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#BABABA" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Create **normal_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#B3E5FC"
        android:startColor="#B3E5FC" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#BABABA" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Apply it on button

```
<Button
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, but it didn't solve the problem. BTW the I can not see the button in designer tab of Main.axml. When I remove the line android:background="@drawable/button_background" the button becomes visible

Answer (score 0):

Change `https` to `http` in

`<selector xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Also rename your drawable xml file `ButtonSignInStyle.xml` to lowercase `button_signin_style.xml`

Comment: I started with http but it couldn't find <selector> in the beginning so i've changed to https. I did what you suggested and it is working now. Thanks a lot! you saved the day for me.

Comment: Sorry Mohit, I tried to mark is as an answer, but it says "Votes cast by those with less then '15 reputation' are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score". I have only 4 reputation. :(

Comment: It's ok. Enjoy the day.